# perceptive height and width of object from distance

Tags: calculus

assume we have a box that measures length of it is about one meter. what is percepted  size of it for someone looking to it at  100 meter distance?

I'm working on a shooting project that I need to scale 2d hunting goal sprites to make them look from distance.

Comment: "Perceptive height" you talk about is probably steradian which is roughly same as angle in three dimension

Comment: @user160738 I don't know what are you talking about I'm just asking about what is size of object for some one looking at it in distance and assume there is no angle between eye and object

Comment: steradian is like a 3 dimensional angle, similar to how a circle has radians, a sphere has them

Comment: @virtuoso: the size is "about one meter", of course. What do you _really_ want to know? I mean that as a serious question!

Comment: @TonyK I think question is obvious. what is size if object in distance for someone looking at it from a distance. when you see object form distance you see it with less size. so what is that size depending on the distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perceived size, as the visual angle, can be computed as the angle of a right triangle, with adjacent cathetus of 100m and opposite of 1m. So you can obtain the angle by arctan( 1/100 ) = 0.5729°. If you want to find the size on a projected surface, such as a screen 'd' meters away from the subject, you can use another right triangle with that same angle, with adjacent cathetus = 'd' and opposite cathetus is 's', what you are looking for. Than you have s = tan( 0.5729° )*d = 0.01*d.
That can also be thought using similar triangles. Being 'D' the real distance (100m), 'd' the distance of the projected surface, 'S' the real size (1m) and 's' the size on the surface, you also get that s = d*S/D.